# Inequality for the Integral of a Composition?

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Assume we have a real interval $I = [a,b]$ and two real continuous functions $f : I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g:f(I)\rightarrow\mathbb{[0,\infty)}$. I am interested in the following: Does
$$\int\limits_a^b g(f(t))dt \geq \int\limits_{f(I)} g(x)d x$$
hold? Intuitively this should be true, since $f(t)$ might hit some points in $f(I)$ several times for different values $t\in I$, while each of those values is only hit once when integrating over $f(I)$ (and since $g\geq 0$, this can only decrease the value of the integral).

However, I also have the feeling like there is a very trivial counter example to this, since I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: It’s unfortunately not true, take for instance $g(x) = x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Then $\int_0^1 g(f(x)) dx = 1/3$ while $\int_0^1 g(x)dx = 1/2$.

Comment: However, you might be interested in Jensen’s inequality, which states that for a convex function $\phi$, $\int_0^1 \phi(f(x)) dx \geq \phi (\int_0^1 f(x) dx )$.

Comment: @kieransquared thank you very much!